# sympyのsymbolsで作成した数式のリストへの追加

Tags: python, sympy

sympy.symbolsで定義した数式のリストへの追加について質問致します。

sympy.symbolsでx, yを定義し、数式Fを定義した時、for文内において
Fの係数を計算し複数のFを自動で生成する際に、それらのFを順番にリス
トF_listに追加したいのですが、F_list.extend(F)を使うとエラーが出
てしまいます。
何か良い方法はないでしょうか。

Comment: 分かりにくい質問にも関わらず、ご丁寧にありがとうございました。仰せの通り解決致しました。

Comment: お疲れさまでした。スタック・オーバーフローでは、回答の横のチェックマークをクリックすることで[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)することができます。どうぞお試しください :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extend() ではなくて append() の間違いなのでは？

```
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')

F_list = []
for i in range(10):
    F = i * x + y
    F_list.append(F)

print(F_list)
#[y, x + y, 2*x + y, 3*x + y, 4*x + y, 5*x + y, 6*x + y, 7*x + y, 8*x + y, 9*x + y]
```